# Is firebase auth().onAuthStateChanged performing a fetch?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was under the assumption that firebase's `auth().onAuthStateChanged()` performs a fetch to check if user is authenticated, but I'm unable to see any request in network tab. What exactly is this function doing and when is it triggered / changing state, and initially is it performing any sort of fetch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you attach a function to Firebase Authentication's `onAuthStateChanged()`, that function is called:

- straight away with the current authentication state of the user AND
- whenever the user's authentication state changes

Attaching a listener does not require any network traffic. It just returns the current known state, which the Firebase Authentication client tracks in memory and in local storage.

Of course when the state changes, there is likely network traffic that leads up to that. But the act of attaching a listener itself is not causing network traffic.